# How to combine getopts and positional parameters in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, parameters, getopts

I want to use both `getopts` and positional parameters, but if I pass in a positional parameter to the program the `getopts` get lost.

```
directory=$1

while getopts l: flag; do
  case "$flag" in
    l) level=$OPTARG;;
  esac
done

if [ -n "$level" ]; then
  echo "Level exist!"
else
  echo "Level doesn't exist!"
fi
```

So when I run the program like this:

```
sh myprogram.sh ~/documents -l 2
```

I expect:

`Level exist!`

And instead it returns:

`Level doesn't exist!`

The thing is, if I run the program without the positional parameter (~/documents) like this:

`sh myprogram.sh -l 2`

I get the correct output:

`Level exist!`

Why is that? How can I use both positional parameters and `getopts` in bash?

Thanks!

Comment: If you know for sure that the first positional parameter is going to be your directory, you can just use `shift` after the assignment `directory=$1`. But, as pointed out, it's probably better to just follow established practice.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Most tools are written in the form: `tool [options] arg ...`

So you would do this:

```
# first, parse the options:
while getopts l: flag; do
  case "$flag" in
    l) level=$OPTARG;;
    \?) exit 42;;
  esac
done

# and shift them away
shift $((OPTIND - 1))

# validation
if [ -n "$level" ]; then
  echo "Level exist!"
else
  echo "Level doesn't exist!"
fi

# THEN, access the positional params
echo "there are $# positional params remaining"
for ((i=1; i<=$#; i++)); do
  printf "%d\t%s\n" $i "${!i}"
done
```

Use the `\?` to abort the script if the user provides an unknown option or fails to provide a required argument

And invoke it like:

```
$ bash test.sh
Level doesn't exist!
there are 0 positional params remaining

$ bash test.sh -l 2
Level exist!
there are 0 positional params remaining

$ bash test.sh -l 2 foo bar
Level exist!
there are 2 positional params remaining
1   foo
2   bar

$ bash test.sh -x
test.sh: illegal option -- x

$ bash test.sh -l
test.sh: option requires an argument -- l
```

But you **cannot** put the options after the arguments: getopts stops when the first non-option argument is found

```
$ bash test.sh foo bar -l 2
Level doesn't exist!
there are 4 positional params remaining
1   foo
2   bar
3   -l
4   2
```

Comment: Nice! It worked, so there isn't any workaround to put the opts after the params?

Comment: Not with `getopts`. There is an external program call `getopt` that can do it. It's a little harder to work with. Here's an example: https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/vivid/util-linux/vivid/view/head:/misc-utils/getopt-parse.bash